# sorl thumbnail complains that table sessioncache does not exist

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, sorl-thumbnail

I am using sorl thumbnails to generate thumbnails in a view. I installed

```
mysql-python
Django==1.6.1
Pillow==2.3
sorl-thumbnail==11.12.1b
```

I have added

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

and
`'sorl.thumbnail',` to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.
Ran

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

which created the "thumbnail.kvstore" table in my "archives" database and have the following in my model:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
class relic(models.Model):
...
    photo               = ImageField(upload_to='photo', blank=True, null=True)
```

In my view I have

```
# all the relics for the given historical site (hsite_id)
def relicList(request, hsite_id):
    print hsite_id
    theSite         = historical_site.objects.get(pk=hsite_id)
    relicSet        = theSite.relic_set.all()

    return render_to_response('archives/relic_list.html', locals())

# end relicList
```

In my template I have

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for relic in relicSet %}
<!-- alternate colours with the classes defined in the style sheet -->
<tr class={% cycle "odd" "even" %}> 

    <td>{{ relic.name }}</td><td>{{ relic.description }}</td>
    <td>
    {% if relic.photo %}
        <a href="{{ relic.photo.url }}">
        {% thumbnail relic.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
            <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}
         </a>
    {% endif %}
    </td>


</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Loading the template gives me

```
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'archives.sessioncache' doesn't exist")
```

Trying a few other things I tried

```
(archeologist)jason:>./manage.py shell
>>> from achives.models import *
>>> from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
>>> myRelics = relic.objects.all()
>>> for r in myRelics:
...     print r.photo
etc
>>> print r.photo
photo/image_9.jpg
>>> im = get_thumbnail(r.photo, '100x100', crop='center')
```

I get the same error

```
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'archives.sessioncache' doesn't exist")
```

I don't have memcached installed, and I already use thumbnails successfully from another project that uses postgres. I don't want to use memcached, as this is a small project. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in my settings.py file. I had this setting, which I did not understand

```
CACHES  = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND' : 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION' : 'sessioncache',
    }
}
```

Once I commented it out, thumbnails worked fine.